# How to analyze last commit with sonarqube?

Tags: git, sonarqube, integration

http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Local+and+Branch+Analysis
How to check my commit with sonarQube server + sonarQube Github plugin?
Thank you for answer.

Comment: if you use jenkins to analyse your project with sonarqube you can look at github webhook

Comment: I use maven, can I analyze somehow may last commit in my local repo.

Answer (score 1):

The [GitHub plugin docs](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/GitHub+Plugin) should help you !